# Can you extend "_layouts/cp" in a plugin settings page?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm aware that I could enable the plugin to have it's own CP section, but I don't feel that this would be the right place for it to live due to its nature, when you view the settings page it wouldn't be a list of inputs, it would be a table view.

Ideally the plugin page would reside in `settings > plugins > myPlugin` but have the same template as a plugin with a CP section, just like the sections settings page.

This is my template in `pluginHandle/settings.html`

```
{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

{% set title = "My Plugin" %}

{% set content %}
  Some content should appear here maybe?
{% endset %}
```

I don't get any errors when I view the page it just looks like this:

[image: Plugin settings page]

As you can see the title variable gets ignored and has taken the plugin name, but if I remove the `{% set title = '' %}` part it throws an error of `Variable "title" does not exist`.

I tried to match the basics of what the sections settings template that craft has. Am I just trying to do something that was never an intended purpose or is just bad practice ?

Any clearance would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your settings page doesn't need to include `{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}`.

Also there's no need to define any block section. What's in your *template/settings.html* file will be shown within that CP-area per default.

Comment: Yeah you're right, the issue I have with this though is that it's wrapped in a form element with a save button at the bottom, this is something I want to avoid and I figured extending _layouts/cp would be the way to go about that.

Comment: You _could_ use the `{% redirect %}` tag on your settings page and redirect the user to another page with your own custom settings. It's not super-fancy but it might work if you need to make something very custom...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I will go down the redirect route, that way if I do end up needing settings it'll be easier to switch it out etc

Comment: I just tried to do the same, get rid of that "Save" button on a settings page. `redirect` sounded like a good suggestion but it didn't work for me, because it redirected each and every settings page with that set up (even settings/plugins !). Did you get that working or found another solution, @AlecRitson?

Comment: Hey @carlcs I dont think i did, in the end I just changed the way things were saved in the plugin to use the default settings form, i'd be interested in figuring this out though in the future for sure.

Comment: @Alec I found out that it work if you use `setSettingsUrl` instead of `setSettingsHtml`. Stupid us ;)